# aggregate one column to different fields according to another column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have a table like

```
id country   os         sales
1  us        android    100
2  us        ios        50
```

I want to aggregate them to one record like

```
id country android_sales ios_sales
1  us      100           50
```

I have simplified the situation, so using max or min function may not be accurate, only based on string comparing.
I have a solution like

```
select sum((os='android')*sales) as android_sales, 
       sum((os='ios')*sales) as ios_sales 
group by country
```

but I feel like it is too complicated, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation . . . a `case` inside a `sum()`:

```
select country,
       sum(case when os = 'android' then sales else 0 end) as sales_android,
       sum(case when os = 'ios' then sales else 0 end) as sales_ios
from t
group by country;
```

The `id` is probably not needed for your results.  If you do want an id from the table, then add `min(id)`.

Comment: I wonder if the sales column is not integer, like varchar or datetime, and sum function does not work, how to do it?use udf?

Comment: @user8131108 . . . I would use an explicit conversion to a number.  `sum()` doesn't work on `datetime`, because addition doesn't make sense on that data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select min(id), country, 
       sum(case when os = 'android' then sales else 0 end) as android_sales,
       sum(case when os = 'ios' then sales else 0 end) as ios_sales
from table t
group by country;
```

Comment: I have a question that if `sum((os='android')*sales)` will scan os and sales of all records and calculate, `sum(case when os = 'android' then sales else 0 end)` only scan os column and return one sales value so be faster?or the difference can be ignored?